# angular cli not able to install, getting error as `Cannot find module 'hosted-git-info' `

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to create new project using `ng new` but getting error as :

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'hosted-git-info'
```

here is the detailed log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\MB112830\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--quiet' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'hosted-git-info'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MB112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:3:21)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
5 verbose cwd E:\Tutorials\Angular2\NG5\new-way
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.10240
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MB112830\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
8 verbose node v8.9.4
9 verbose npm  v5.7.1
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'hosted-git-info'
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

what is the issue here? how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the files are corrupted or deleted.So follows the below steps.

1.Uninstall node.

2.Delete `npm` and `npm-cache` folder from `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming`

3.Install node.

It works!.

Answer (score -1):

Hi as i can see your project in E: drive please try to install angular in C drive globally.

> npm install -g @angular/cli
>   after installation please create a project folder name(client) by
>   c://>ng new client 
>   after creation of new project go inside client folder
>   C:// > cd client
>   c:// > client>ng serve
>   Open browser with localhost:4200 you can see your angular home page in running mode.
>   :)Cheers